# WPF Margin-Property will not update in Control Template Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.8

I have a custom Window Style and therefore, I want to change the Margin-Property of a grid inside a control template within a Control Template Trigger.

```
<Style x:Key="BaseWindow" TargetType="Window">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Grid x:Name="Grid">
            ....
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                    <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                </Trigger>
            /ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I have tested the Trigger with other controls that are inside the Grid Control, there the margin uptates but not the margin of the grid control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what seems to be the issue, but I created an example window and the margin changed correctly, maybe you can figure out what is missing from the example (maybe you didn't apply the style to the window?):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="White">
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200" Text="pppp" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Margin" Value="45"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```